# How to add the iPhone X screen dimensions to the mix of different iPhone screen sizes

Tags: unity, ios, iphone

Generally for Unity I design all my artwork in Illustrator. So I start off with 1440x1920 (for portrait games) and outline a red frame of 1080x1920. So everything that fits well within the 1080x1920 usually covers the family of iOS devices for me. Then I set the  Pixels Per Unit to 192 for all my images. This approach has really served me well. Now that the iPhone X is in the mix, how can I cater for it in a similar way?

Comment: Lots of ways to deal with this. My personal means of dealing with different aspects is to pick one, and fix it. I let Unity generate black bars on top/bottom or left/right to keep the game screen fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Even without taking the X into account you had to support 3 screen ratios for iOS:

- 3:4 for iPads
- 2:3 for older iPhones
- 9:16 for newer iPhones

So presumably you already take that into account in the display of the game? Or maybe you let Unity place bands?

In any case, the way to do it is to specify an area that will fit inside all the target devices then add padding/background/etc on the sides. If you look at Clash Royale screenshot on iPad for instance, you can see that you see a lot more of the sides of the arenas.

Then you set your Canvases and Camera's projection to target a specific height of a screen and let Unity scale as needed.